# Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $ JSON Array Kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, mvvm, retrofit

I want to retrieve a JSON Array, How can I adjust my codebase to that. I have used the retrofit library to retrieve the data and I used the MVVM architecture. I get the error Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $.

this is my endpoint class:

```
 @GET("v2/venues/search")
    fun fetchAllVenues(): Call<List<Venue>>
    }
```

this is my Repository class:

```
class VenueRepository {

    private var apiInterface: VenuesEndpoint? = null

    init {
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getApiClient().create(VenuesEndpoint::class.java)
    }

    fun fetchAllVenues(): MutableLiveData<List<Venue>?> {

        val data = MutableLiveData<List<Venue>?>()

        apiInterface?.fetchAllVenues()?.enqueue(object : Callback<List<Venue>> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<Venue>>, t: Throwable) {
                data.value = null
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<Venue>>,
                response: Response<List<Venue>>
            ) {

                val res = response.body()
                if (response.code() == 200 && res != null) {
                    data.value = res
                } else {
                    data.value = null
                }

            }
        })

        return data

    }


}
```

and this is my model class:

```
data class Venue(var id:Int,var name:String)
```

and this is my viewmodel class:

```
class VenueViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var venueRepository: VenueRepository? = null
    var postModelListLiveData: MutableLiveData<List<Venue>?>? = null


    init {
        venueRepository = VenueRepository()
        postModelListLiveData = MutableLiveData()
    }

    fun fetchAllVenues() {
        postModelListLiveData = venueRepository?.fetchAllVenues()

    }


}
```

this is the JSON I want to retrieve:

```
"response": { "venues": [ { "id": "4b83cb72f964a520d71031e3" "name": "Stadhuis" "contact": { "phone": "+3114010" "formattedPhone": "+31 14010" "twitter": "rotterdam" } "location": { "address": "Coolsingel 40" "lat": 51.92258962728412 "lng": 4.480227190204032 "labeledLatLngs": [ "0": { "label": "display" "lat": 51.92258962728412 "lng": 4.480227190204032 } ] "postalCode": "3011 AD" "cc": "NL" "city": "Rotterdam" "state": "Zuid-Holland" "country": "Nederland" "formattedAddress": [ "0": "Coolsingel 40" "1": "3011 AD Rotterdam" "2": "Nederland"
```

Comment: Can you share the json looks like?

Comment: "response": {
"venues": [
{
"id": "4b83cb72f964a520d71031e3"
"name": "Stadhuis"
"contact": {
"phone": "+3114010"
"formattedPhone": "+31 14010"
"twitter": "rotterdam"
}
"location": {
"address": "Coolsingel 40"
"lat": 51.92258962728412
"lng": 4.480227190204032
"labeledLatLngs": [
"0": {
"label": "display"
"lat": 51.92258962728412
"lng": 4.480227190204032
}
]
"postalCode": "3011 AD"
"cc": "NL"
"city": "Rotterdam"
"state": "Zuid-Holland"
"country": "Nederland"
"formattedAddress": [
"0": "Coolsingel 40"
"1": "3011 AD Rotterdam"
"2": "Nederland"
]
}

Comment: You may update your question and include the json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, the response returns you `venues` and you are expecting a `List<Venue>`, so what should work for you is, create another data class that is like this:

```
data class Venues(
 val venues: List<Venue>
)
```

and then inside the `GET` request return `Call<Venues>`
Do tell if that fixes it for you :)

**UPDATE**

Ok, that was a bit lengthy conversation but finally here is your detailed solution, hope this resolves everything for you!

> ViewModel

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class ViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val repository = Repository()

    fun getData(longLat: String, date: String): LiveData<mainResponse?> {

        repository.fetch(longLat, date)
        return repository.data
    }
}
```

> Repository

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

class Repository {

    private val _data: MutableLiveData<mainResponse?> = MutableLiveData(null)
    val data: LiveData<mainResponse?> get() = _data

    fun fetch(longlat: String, date: String) {

        val retrofit = Retro()
        val api = retrofit.retro.create(api::class.java)

        api.get(
            longLat = longlat,
            date = date
        ).enqueue(object : Callback<mainResponse>{

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<mainResponse>, response: Response<mainResponse>) {

                val res = response.body()
                if (response.code() == 200 && res != null) {

                    _data.value = res

                } else {

                    _data.value = null
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<mainResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                _data.value = null
            }
        })
    }
}
```

> MainActivity

```
private val viewModel by viewModels<ViewModel>()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    viewModel.getData(
        longLat = "40.7,-74", // sample latitude and longitude
        date = "20210715" // date format is: YYYYMMDD
    ).observe(this, Observer {

        it?.let { res ->

            res.response.venues.forEach { venue ->

                val name = venue.name
                val location = venue.location

                Log.d("name ",name)
                Log.d("address ", location.address)
            }
        }
    })
  }
}
```

> Api Interface

```
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.GET
import retrofit2.http.Query

interface api {

    @GET("v2/venues/search")
    fun get(
        @Query("ll") longLat: String,
        @Query("client_id") id: String = Const.clientId,
        @Query("client_secret") secret: String = Const.clientSecret,
        @Query("v") date: String
    ): Call<mainResponse>
}
```

> **Model Classes**

> mainResponse

data class mainResponse(
val response: Response
)

> Response

```
data class Response(
val venues: List<Venue>,
val confident: Boolean
)
```

> Location

```
data class Location(
val address: String,
val crossStreet: String,
val lng: Double,
val lat: Double
)
```

> Venue

```
data class Venue(
val id: String,
val name: String,
val location: Location
)
```

> Const

```
object Const {

const val BASE_URL = "https://api.foursquare.com"
const val clientId = "" // add yours
const val clientSecret = "" // add yours
}
```

> Retro

```
class Retro {

val retro = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(Const.BASE_URL)
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build()
}
```

> **Dependencies: make sure to add activity-ktx for using ViewModel in activity**

```
def coroutines_version = "1.4.2"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$coroutines_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$coroutines_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:$coroutines_version"

def lifecycle_version = "2.3.1"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

def retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"

implementation "androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.3"
```

Comment: How should I adjust the repository class?

Comment: change `data` to `MutableLiveData<Venues>` and `Call` also to `Call<Venues>`.

Comment: you need to make changes in `ViewModel` as well similarly, and the return type of that function inside the repository too

Comment: i have in mine MainActivity this code.  venuesViewModel.postModelListLiveData?.observe(this, Observer {
            if (it!=null){
                rv_home.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                adapter.setData(it as ArrayList<Venue>)
            }else{
                println("something went wrong")
            }
            progress_home.visibility = View.GONE
        }) how can I change this?

Comment: so when you call `adapter.setData(it)` basically now you need to change it to `adapter.setData(it.venues)` :)

Comment: do tell if that fixed it for you and kindly mark it as accepted solution, or continue with any queries that you might have :)

Comment: I get the error kotlin.TypeCastException: null cannot be cast to non-null type kotlin.collections.ArrayList<com.android.assessment.model.Venue> /* = java.util.ArrayList<com.android.assessment.model.Venue> */

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234874/discussion-between-user3761485-and-mehul-bisht).

Comment: Hi Mehul it worked like a charm, I have only one question when adres is null the app crash. Do you know a fix for that?

Comment: yes, you can surround the api call method inside a `try catch` block, the catch block will be called whenever there is an `HTTP Exception` so you can set the data of `MutableLiveData` to null there and only set to adapter it the value is not null

Comment: Can you show where I can put the try and catch also, how can i send the data to the adapter like this? adapter.setData(it as ArrayList<Venue>) because it showing now an error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.assessment.model.mainResponse cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

Comment: for `setData()` you need `it.response.venues` will give you a `List<Venue>`, so change `ArrayList<Venue>` to `List<Venue>` accordingly.